# Neo4j with Spring: No bean named 'getSessionFactory' available

Tags: java, spring, neo4j

I'm new to neo4j and spring in combination and spring at all. When I start debugging, I get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'getSessionFactory' available

Can anyone help me please?

apllication-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="de.unileipzig.analyzewikipedia.neo4j" />

    <!--neo4j:config storeDirectory="C:/temp/neo4jdatabase" base-package="de.unileipzig.analyzewikipedia.neo4j.dataobjects"/-->

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="de.unileipzig.analyzewikipedia.neo4j.repositories"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.GraphDatabaseServiceFactoryBean"
          destroy-method="shutdown" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg value="C:/develop/uni/analyze-wikipedia-netbeans/database"/>
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Startup-Class

package de.unileipzig.analyzewikipedia.neo4j.console;

```
import de.unileipzig.analyzewikipedia.neo4j.dataobjects.Article;
import de.unileipzig.analyzewikipedia.neo4j.service.ArticleService;
import java.io.File;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Neo4JConsole {
    /**
     * MAIN: start the java file
     * 
     * @param args as string array
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String cwd = (new File(".")).getAbsolutePath();
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("application-context.xml");
        ArticleService service = (ArticleService) context.getBean("articleService");

        Article art = createArticle();
        createArticle(service, art);

        System.out.println("Article created");
    }    

    private static Article createArticle() {
        Article article = new Article();
        article.setTitle("Title");
        return article;
    }

    private static Article createArticle(ArticleService service, Article art) {
        return service.create(art);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you post the full exception log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have this configuration?

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("org.neo4j.cineasts.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("org.neo4j.cineasts")
public class PersistenceContext extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.cineasts.domain");
    }
}
```

For more information, try to look [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/spring-data-neo4j/)